# Trouble resolving a promise when getting subcategories

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

In the code below, I am getting `undefined` as the value of `subs` and I'm not sure why. I am relatively new to working with Promises and async functions so I'm sure I'm just missing something here.

```
let select = document.querySelector("#category");

async function getMainCategories() {
  const categoriesURL = "INSERT_URL/categories_main";
  return await fetch(categoriesURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((categories) => {
      categories
        .sort(function (a, b) {
          var nameA = a.title.toUpperCase();
          var nameB = b.title.toUpperCase();
          if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
          }
          return 0;
        })
        .map((cat) => {
          const subs = Promise.all(getSubcategories(cat.id)); //err - object is not iterable
          return `<optgroup label="${cat.title}">${subs}</optgroup>`;
        });
    });
}

async function getSubcategories(id) {
  let subcategoriesURL = "INSERT_URL/subcategories";

  return await fetch(subcategoriesURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((subcategories) => {
      subcategories
        .sort(function (a, b) {
          var nameA = a.title.toUpperCase();
          var nameB = b.title.toUpperCase();
          if (nameA < nameB) {
            return -1;
          }
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            return 1;
          }

          // names must be equal
          return 0;
        })
        .filter((subcategory) => subcategory.categories_main_id === id)
        .map((sub) => {
          return `<option value="${sub.id}">${sub.title}</option>`;
        });
    });
}

async function setHTML() {
  console.log(await getMainCategories()); // undefined
  select.innerHTML =
    "<option disabled selected>Select a category</option>" +
    (await getMainCategories());
}

setHTML();
```

Comment: You need `Promise.all` to wait for the promises you create in that `map` loop.

Comment: Also don't use a global `str` variable, but have each function **`return`** the respective string value it produces, then join them together

Comment: @Bergi I tried both of those things and I'm still getting `undefined`

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to show how?

Comment: @Bergi updated!